# Spring. Resolve circular dependency with java config and without @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I've got circular dependency and java config. While resolving it with xml config is very easy I can't resolve it with java config without @Autowired. Beans:

```
public class A {
    private B b;

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public class B {
    private A a;

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

I've tried this(I've read that with @Bean annotation Spring won't invoke method every time bean is referenced, but in this case it's actually been invoked all the time):

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public A a() {
        A a = new A();
        a.setB(b());
        return a;
    }

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        B b = new B();
        b.setA(a());
        return b;
    }
}
```

And this, with @Autowired of Configuration class fields:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Autowired
    A a;
    @Autowired
    B b;

    @Bean
    public A a() {
        A a = new A();
        a.setB(b);
        return a;
    }

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        B b = new B();
        b.setA(a);
        return b;
    }
}
```

Also I've tried all above with @Lazy annotation. Doesn't help. But works perfectly if I annotate setters of A and B with @Autowired. But it's not what I want right now. What am I doing wrong and is there any way to resolve Circular dependency in java config without usage of @Autowired?

Comment: Can you explain _But it's not what I want right now._? If it's the right tool for the job...

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis my app is little messy right now and I'm afraid to get confused with dependencies all around the code. It's not religious and I love Autowired, but right now I'd prefer to concentrate beans in one config file and manage dependencies by hands. Also I wonder if it's possible at all.

Comment: There was an interesting discussion on spring's forum: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/127799-circular-dependencies-with-autowired-in-java-based-configuration

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behavior you want to get is the following

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.setB(b);
b.setA(a);
```

`@Bean` methods don't give you that. They run to completion to provide a bean instance.

You basically have to partially create one of the instances, then finish initializing it when you've created the other.

```
@Configuration
class Config {
    @Bean
    public A a() {
        A a = new A();
        return a;
    }

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        B b = new B();
        A a = a();
        b.setA(a);
        a.setB(b);
        return b;
    }
}
```

or

```
@Bean
public B b(A a) {
    B b = new B();
    b.setA(a);
    a.setB(b);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: The method `b` could `@Autowire` bean `a` as well (to avoid an implicit call to method `a()`. Isn't that right?

Comment: @wassgren Absolutely. Though it doesn't need explicit `@Autowired`.

Comment: But this will mean that a and b get undecorated references to each other. Annotations will not work.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach using `@Autowired` and `@Component` is to use this pattern:

```
@Component
class A {
    private B b;

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(final B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}


@Component
class B {
    private final A a;

    @Autowired
    public B(final A a) {
        this.a = a;
        a.setB(this);
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

This eliminates the need for a separate `@Configuration`-class. Furthermore, the `setB`-method can possibly be package-protected if the classes exist in the same package to minimize scoping as much as possible.

Comment: Your answer is also useful, it's sad I can't vote up because I'm novice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add another possible solution for your code. Instead of setting circular dependencies right in the config:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public A a() {
        A a = new A();
        a.setB(b());
        return a;
    }

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        B b = new B();
        b.setA(a());
        return b;
    }
}
```

You could also let the spring do the work with the power of @Autowired annotation.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public A a() {
        A a = new A();
        return a;
    }

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        B b = new B();
        return b;
    }
}

public class A {
    private B b;

    @Autowired
    public setB(B b) { this.b = b; }
}

public class B {
    private A a;

    @Autowired
    public setA(A a) { this.a = a; }
}
```

Of course it is non trivial from the "clean/readable/understandable" point of view because now your configuration is mixed in @Configuration and class itself. But as circular dependencies are quite rare, we could afford the hack.

Comment: The point was to do it **without** `@Autowired` (though don't ask me why).

Comment: Oh, I see. Anyway, let it be here. Thanks.